# rails handling devise multiple users

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan, sti

## routes.rb

```
  get "main/index"
  match "profile" => "main#profile"
  match "account" => "main#account"
  match "subjects" => "main#subjects"
  match "messages" => "main#messages"
  match "homework" => "main#homework"
  devise_for :students,:teachers
```

## app/models/user_profile.rb

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :gender, :institute_id, :last_name, :new_lesson, :new_messages, :user_type, :year,:avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },:default_url => '/assets/default_avatar.png'
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

## model user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me , :user_profile_attributes
  has_one :user_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile
end
```

## model student.rb

```
class Student < User
end
```

## model teacher.rb

```
class Teacher < User
end
```

## migration for user

```
class AddTypeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :type, :string
  end
end
```

## migrations for user_profile

```
class CreateUserProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_profiles do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.integer :user_type
      t.integer :gender
      t.integer :year
      t.integer :institute_id
      t.integer :new_messages
      t.integer :new_lesson
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

## doubt

basically what i am doing is, generating a devise user model , and then through STI i am inheriting Student and Teacher from the user model , i have also created a UserProfile model with OneToOne relationship with user model and hence also with student and teacher model ,UserProfile model is generated to have all the common fields such as avatar , first name , last name , institute id etc.

I have 3 doubts

first, Is there any simpler way to implement the usage of `current_user` session variable provided by devise , in this case there would be two session variables, one for teacher and one for students for eg `current_teacher` and `current_student` , so my question is , is there any way to just replace both the variables by one common variable

second , When i create a new user a new user_profile is created , but when i create a new student and i check `somestudent.user_profile` , it returns nil

third , Is there any nice implementation for STI or cancan roles to exactly meet my needs and implement what i am looking for?

Please help , thanks in advance

Comment: rather than using inheritance, why not use roles. This way you can use cancan authorization. and u can also use a single current_user method

Comment: then during sign_up how would i set roles for students and teachers ??
then i guess i have to do it via urls , could you suggest a decent implementation of cancan?